# How to reference page numbers in Powerpoint?

Tags: powerpoint

Is there a way to reference page numbers in PowerPoint, the way one can do in Word? For example, I'd like to be able to write "details on page 10" and to have the number 10 updated automatically if the page number changes because I have added or removed other slides.

Answer (score 1):

No, afraid not, at least not out of the box, though one might be able to write an add-in that updated everything when the user clicks a button or (with more effort) automatically when they add/remove a slide.

Comment: why is such a POS so used in the corporate world if it fails at even the most basic tasks like this one?

Comment: Possibly because what you consider a basic task isn't on everyone else's required features list. Or, equally likely, because corporates buy Office to get Excel and Word and ... oh, look, free presentation software!  Use PowerPoint, y'all.